How do I enable Wire GraphQL in an LWC for Guest Users on CommerceCloud sites?
Background
I have a site powered by CommerceCloud/ExperienceCloud. We allow guest users to access most pages of the site. I have built a custom lightning web component that queries public data (products), to try to do a special custom search. I'm using the GraphQL Wire adaptor, which I've successfully used in a number of other LWCs in the backend to query other types of records.
Code
@wire(graphql, {
    query: gql`
        query records($filters: Product2_Filter, $orderBy: Product2_OrderBy) {
            uiapi {
                query {
                    Product2(
                        where: $filters,
                        orderBy: $orderBy
                    ){
                        totalCount
                        edges {
                            node {
                                Id
                                Name { value }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    `,
    variables: "$queryParameters",
})
graphqlQueryResult({ data, errors }) {
    if (errors) {
        console.log(errors);
    } else if (data) {
        if (this.loading) {
            this.records = this.list.unpackRecords(data.uiapi.query[this.list.objectName].edges.map((edge) => edge.node));
            this.loading = false;
        }
    }
}

Problem
The call works perfectly when a user is authenticated. But if the user is an unauthenticated guest user, I get the following error:
{errorCode: 'FUNCTIONALITY_NOT_ENABLED', message: 'This feature is not currently enabled for this user.', statusCode: 403}

Things I've Checked
I went to the guest profile under the Site, and ensured that the API system permission is enabled:

Question
What am I missing? How do I enable this?

Are you having the same issue with logged users?

Hi, i have exactly the same error, have you find a solution to fix it?

@user3808750 No problem with logged user
